# How to upgrade packages versions using project requirements file in PyCharm 3.1.1

Tags: python, pycharm

I know that this is doable from the command line and I've been using it, but since location of project's `requirements.txt` file can be defined in PyCharm I wonder how does PyCharm use this knowledge?

Is there a way to install requirements from that file using PyCharm or to update file if the package is installed or both?

**Edit:** Problem is that PyCharm does suggest installation of missing dependency and update of `requirements.txt` file as stated in docs [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/resolving-unsatisfied-dependencies.html) and [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/populating-dependencies-management-files.html), but it does not suggest an upgrade if the version is not equal to the one stated in requirements file using `package==ver` or `package>=ver`.

Comment: For me PyChanrm automatically find requirements.txt and suggest to install missed packages. Anyway, you can install it manually or open settings->python interpreters->configure interpreter and install/browse installed python libs

Comment: I will need to investigate this.

Comment: Please submit a feature request to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Answer (score 2):

This was solved in a later version of PyCharm.